# Why i am getting Tree conflict here?

Tags: svn, svn-merge, tree-conflict

Current project structure in SVN

`Trunk > Folder 1> it contains further folders like A, B,C`

I have created the branches from Folder 1.

Now i realized Folder 1 is redundant.Basically Structure should

`Trunk > it contains further folders like A, B,C`

**What i am planning to do**

1) First copied the folder A,B,C into Trunk. So structure becomes like this
    `Trunk > Folder 1> it contains further folders like A, B,C`
    `Trunk > it also contains further folders like A, B,C`

2) Merge branch to Trunk so that Modifications under Branch folder (A,B,C) get merged to `A,B,C under Trunk`

3) Then delete Folder 1 from trunk

**But at step 2 i am getting Tree conflict error . I am not sure why ?**

Comment: If you want to merge to new folders (copied folders) then you probably have to merge each folder separately. If you want to merge them in one operation then merge them first, and copy them later. Or, you could move the `Folder 1` to root, delete trunk, and rename `Folder 1` to `trunk`. And then merge in one go. But not sure if that will actually work.

Comment: Wrote in comment because not sure if this above is the correct answer. If it is please let me know, so I make it a proper one.

Comment: Can you post the specific tree conflict message? From a first look, if you really just copied (and did not delete) folders A-C in step 1), there should be no conflict.